# Why does compiling with "mvn --update-snapshots install" fail, but immediately following with "mvn install" succeeds?

Tags: java, maven, java-11

I've got a project with a bunch of modules that I'm trying to compile and run, and there's one module giving me trouble. The problem is the same in IntelliJ as on the command line ("error: cannot access SomeClass. class file for SomeClass not found"). This file exists in a dependency for the module I am trying to compile.

If I compile this one module with `mvn --update-snapshots -Dmaven.test.skip install`, the build fails. Then I immediately follow this up with `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip install` and it works fine.

Why is this? From what I understand about `-U`, if anything, the second build without the flag should also fail since it'd be referencing the newly pulled down snapshots.

Comment: Do you run the `-U` version with `-Dmaven.test.skip` as well? Have you tried running the "no `-U`" version without `-Dmaven.test.skip`?

Comment: without more accurate information where/when etc. the following errors occur `error: cannot access SomeClass. class file for SomeClass not found` it's hard to help... are those error occuring in your test classes?

Comment: my best guess would be that the missing or outdated dependency is in one of the tests, so the -U fails because it cannot update the dependencies and then stops and doesn't try to do the install phase, but the second attempt just uses stuff on disk and doesn't execute the tests and if the missing class is only in the test scope, it doesn't matter and the build succeeds.